I want to get the properties of the pressed forms button in PHP
I'm trying to make a note change editor in php and MySQL. But I ran into a problem. There are a lot of notes and to get the right one, I decided to stuff the ID, date, text and title into the properties of the button, but I don't know how to get the data of a specific note so that.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id_user = ".$_SESSION['id_user']."";
if($result = mysqli_query($mySql, $sql)){
  $results='';
   foreach($result as $row) {
       $results.='<section class="notes-section section" id="notesCard">
                     <div id= "noteContent" class="note-content">
                         <div class="note-h2"><h2 id="headingH2">'.$row['heading'].'</h2></div>
                         <div class="note-text"><p id="textArea">'.$row['text_content'].'</p></div>
                         <div class="note-panel">
                             <label id="dateNotes" for="">'.$row['date'].'</label>
                             <form action="editNote.php" name="" method="post">
                                <button name="editNotes" id="edit" class="insert-btn btn" value="'.$row['id_notes'].'">Изменить</button>
                                <button name="deleteNotes" class="delete-btn btn" value="'.$row['id_notes'].'">Удалить</button>
                                </form>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                </section>';
     }
  echo $results;
} else {
  echo "Что-то пошло не так...";
}

if (isset($_POST['deleteNotes']) and is_numeric($_POST['deleteNotes'])) {
  $delete = $_POST['deleteNotes'];
  if ($mySql -> query("DELETE FROM `notes` WHERE `id_notes` = '$delete'")) {
    
    echo '<script>window.location = "./notes.php"</script>';
  }
}


Just for information, you know you can go to [ru.so] if you don't want to translate everything

I don't know how to get the data of a specific note so that....so that what? This sentence is not finished. We don't know what you are trying to do, or what exactly is the issue. You said you tried some JavaScript but there is no JavaScript in your code.

send it with the request... add hidden input fields for any data you'd want to receive

There is no real need to have multiple forms as you could simply use AJAX to send the request. However your code is vulnerable to SQL injection currently so perhaps look at using prepared statements to handle the database operations..

Also perhaps worth noting - ID attributes must be unique so adding that code in a loop will create invalid HTML

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

There are several ways you could approach this, one way that would make the page more user friendly would be to use AJAX / Fetch to issue the HTTP requests to your PHP script. This would save reloading the page if multiple items are to be edited.
The following snippet will fail here because of limitations of SO but should give an idea how to send the request on your actual development site. The HTML is a mock up of what might be generated in the PHP code - note the omission of ALL id attributes and addition of the data-id to the section. This dataset attribute is the ID for this db record.


const callback=(text)=>{
  alert(`do something interesting with ${text}`)
};

/*
  This looks at all forms on the page and assigns
  an event handler to look for `click` events that
  are attributed to the buttons within the form.
  
  Using `closest` to identify the parent `section`
  which has been modified to include `data-id` attribute
  (where data-id is the ID from db) rather than assigning
  to each button using `$row['id_notes']`
  
  A `FormData` object is used bring together the values
  you wish to send to the PHP script and the request is made
  using Fetch.
  
  The `callback` here is called when the request has been processed
  by the PHP script and the response sent.
*/
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(f=>{
  f.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement ){
      let section=e.target.closest('section[data-id]')
      let id=section.dataset.id;
      let bttn=e.target.value;

      let fd=new FormData();
        fd.set('id',id);
        fd.set('bttn',bttn);

      console.clear();
      console.log( 'Send POST request to Server -> %s, %s', id, bttn )

      /* send Fetch (ajax) request */
      fetch( 'editNote.php',{ method:'POST', body:fd })
        .then(r=>r.text())
        .then(callback)
        .catch(alert)
    }
  });
})
<section class="notes-section section" data-id="NOTES_ID_1">
  <div id="noteContent" class="note-content">
    <div class="note-h2">
      <h2>This is Heading #1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="note-text">
      <p>This is Paragraph #1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="note-panel">
      <span>This is date #1</span>

      <form action="editNote.php" method="post">
        <button name="action" class="insert-btn btn" value="edit">Изменить</button>
        <button name="action" class="delete-btn btn" value="delete">Удалить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="notes-section section" data-id="NOTES_ID_2">
  <div id="noteContent" class="note-content">
    <div class="note-h2">
      <h2>This is Heading #2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="note-text">
      <p>This is Paragraph #2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="note-panel">
      <span>This is date #2</span>

      <form action="editNote.php" method="post">
        <button name="action" class="insert-btn btn" value="edit">Изменить</button>
        <button name="action" class="delete-btn btn" value="delete">Удалить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="notes-section section" data-id="NOTES_ID_3">
  <div id="noteContent" class="note-content">
    <div class="note-h2">
      <h2>This is Heading #3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="note-text">
      <p>This is Paragraph #3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="note-panel">
      <span>This is date #3</span>

      <form action="editNote.php" method="post">
        <button name="action" class="insert-btn btn" value="edit">Изменить</button>
        <button name="action" class="delete-btn btn" value="delete">Удалить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



The PHP to Process that request could be modified to use a prepared statement like this in simple form. This is untested.
if(isset( 
    $_POST['bttn'],
    $_POST['id']
)){
    if( $bttn=='delete' ){
        $sql='DELETE FROM `notes` WHERE `id_notes`=?';
        
        $stmt=$mySql->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        # this is sent back to the `callback` function
        exit("Record #$id deleted.");
    }
}


Thank you for such a detailed answer, but I thought and did everything through document.location = './editNote.php?addText='+textCon+'&AddDate='+date+'&addHeading='+heading+'&addId='+id;
This option seemed very easy to me and in PHP itself I returned the data via $_GET

Typically you would never use GET to make requests where the database or other resource is modified

If your form contains table with some records, you can name the inputs like this:
$id=1;
echo "<input name='f[$id][name]'>
<input type=submit name='f[$id][edit]' value='Изменить'>
<input type=submit name='f[$id][delete]' value='Удалить'>";

$id=2;
echo "<input name='f[$id][name]'>
<input type=submit name='f[$id][edit]' value='Изменить'>
<input type=submit name='f[$id][delete]' value='Удалить'>";

In this case you will receive an array like that:
$_REQUEST[f]=>[
  1=>[
    name=>'blabla',
    edit=>'Изменить'
  ],
  2=>[
    name=>'blabla2'
  ]
]

The only field 'edit' or 'delete' will appear depending on button clicked.
By the way tag 'button' does not submit form, it is only used in js with 'onclick' event.
Another possibility is to name your buttons like this:
$id=1;
echo "<input name='f[$id][name]'>
<input type=submit name='edit[$id]' value='Изменить'>
<input type=submit name='delete[$id]' value='Удалить'>";

$id=2;
echo "<input name='f[$id][name]'>
<input type=submit name='edit[$id]' value='Изменить'>
<input type=submit name='delete[$id]' value='Удалить'>";

Then the $_REQUEST array will contain only one element
$_REQUEST[edit/delete][your_id]
For example if it is 'edit' then the id you can get with key($_REQUEST[edit]) or array_keys($_REQUEST[edit])[0] or array_key_first($_REQUEST[edit]) (depends on php version)
And one more possibility - you can wrap each record in separate FORM tags. In this case you will reduce post data and get only one record. you only need to put hidden input with record id.
